# Error : The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties : UseSqlServer() in asp.net core 6.0

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0, elsa-workflows

Question: can we specify which method are we using in different namespace?

I am using .NET 6.0 framework with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.10) & Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer (2.9.2).

Code in my `Program.cs`:

```
using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

...

// for Elsa workflow
builder.Services.AddElsa(elsa => elsa
                .UseEntityFrameworkPersistence(ef => ef.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
                .AddConsoleActivities()
                .AddHttpActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Server").Bind)
                .AddJavaScriptActivities());

...

//for existing db connection
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
               options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

...
```

Connection strings in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=.\\SQLExpress; Database=ESEApplicationFormWebApp;uid=kelsey;pwd=12345678;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

I get this error:

> Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties are happening at both .UseSqlServer()

[Error 1 - UseSqlServer() in elsa-workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnE7U.png)

[Error 2 - UseSqlServer() in existing database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELm0c.png)

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer.DbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, System.Type?)' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, System.Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder>?)'

I think the problem is I had installed two NuGet packages with the same method name.

I tried to edit the whole namespace like this but error CS0234 is triggered "The type or namespace name 'UseSqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

Reference:

https://v2.elsaworkflows.io/docs/quickstarts/elsa-dashboard-and-server

https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/installation/installing-persistence

Comment: These are both extension methods? You can call them directly, as you would any static function. `DbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, ..)` vs `SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, ..)`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks! i tried your method and it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the one of two problematic using. Since those methods are extension methods (so static method) you could use them as static method :

```
using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer;
using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.Core.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddElsa(elsa => elsa
                .UseEntityFrameworkPersistence(ef =>
                {
                    ef.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                })
                .AddConsoleActivities()
                .AddHttpActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Server").Bind)
                .AddJavaScriptActivities());
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MvcProjContext>(options =>
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options,builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Or entirely call the static method without removing any usings:

```
using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer;
using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.Core.Extensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddElsa(elsa => elsa
                .UseEntityFrameworkPersistence(ef =>
                {
                    DbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.UseSqlServer(ef,builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                })
                .AddConsoleActivities()
                .AddHttpActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Server").Bind)
                .AddJavaScriptActivities());
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MvcProjContext>(options =>
   SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options,builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: thanks Rena! i tried your method and both are work!!!